# How to filter the ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am calling two ajax function and the url is same ajax.php and both function are fired at the same time now problem is that how to show the response to the correct field

what i am doing

called function 1 and 2

for ex. in one i get steve, jobes and in two rahul, pankaj

i want to show the steve,jobes and rahul, pankaj in different field but

what i am getting  is that both four name displayed in both field now i need to filter those name how to do this?

Comment: Could you show some code please?

Comment: Use querystring variable and check that variable in your ajax.php file.

Comment: can guide you about how to pass the callbacks.... u using `jQuery` or `javascript` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass the callback along with the ajax call which will identify the correct place to populate.

For eg:
for 1st request you will send a callback
`cb1('field1', ajaxresponse);`

and for 2nd request you will send a callback
`cb2('field2', ajaxresponse);`

And then you can use the response as per your need to populate correct field

in jquery

```
function cb1(field, response){
// do your stuff here like innerHTML or value
 $('#'+field).html(response);
 $('#'+field).val(response);
}

function cb2(field, response){
// do your stuff here like innerHTML or value or anything as per your logic depending on response
 $('#'+field).html(response);
 $('#'+field).val(response);
}
```

in javascript

```
function cb1(field, response){
  document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = response;
}

function cb2(field, response){
  document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = response;
}
```

or if the function does the same job then pass the parameter or the initial request param to the function so that it wud populate the correct place

Comment: can post other details if you could guide whether u r using `jQuery` or `javascript`